# What can cause different ObjC/ARC memory behaviour between Release and Debug configuration?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I was running a test to make sure objects are being deallocated properly by wrapping the relevant code section in a 10 second long while loop. I ran the test in Debug and Release configurations with different results.

**Debug** (Build & Run in simulator):

[image: Debug]

**Release** (Build & Run on device, and Profile using Instruments):

[image: Release]

The CPU spikes signify where objects are created and destroyed (there's 3 in each run). Notice how in the Debug build, the memory usage rises gradually during the busy loop, and then settles a little afterwards at a higher base level, this happens with each loop iteration. On the Release build it stays constant the whole time. At the end after 3 runs the memory usage level of the Debug build is significantly higher than that of the Release build. (The CPU spikes are offset on the time axis relative to each other but that's just because I pressed the button that triggers the loop at different times).

The inner loop code in question is very simple and basically consists of a bunch of correctly paired `malloc` and `free` statements as well as a bunch `retain` and `release` calls (courtesy of ARC, also verified as correctly paired).

Any idea what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208685/different-block-behavior-between-debug-and-release-configuration

Answer (score 3):

In Release builds ARC will do its best to keep objects out of the autorelease pool. It does this using objc_returnsRetainAutorelease and checking for it at runtime.

Comment: That could explain why the memory usage stays flat during the loop. But can that affect the memory usage at the end of execution being an order of magnitude higher? I would have thought the run loop would have finished so the pool would have gotten released at the end of the test code (on graphs the spots where the CPU spike drops to 0)?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Cocoa-Touch classes use caching to improve performance. Memory amount used for caching data could vary depending on total memory, available memory and probably some other things. Since you compare results for Mac and device it is not strange that you receive different results.

Some examples of classes/methods that use caching:

> **+(UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name**
>
> Discussion
>
> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and
>   returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not
>   already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the
>   specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.
>
> **NSURLCache**
>
> The NSURLCache class implements the caching of responses to
>   URL load requests by mapping NSURLRequest objects to
>   NSCachedURLResponse objects. It provides a composite in-memory and
>   on-disk cache

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the release builds optimize code and remove debugging information from the code. As a result, the application package is significantly smaller and to load it, less memory is necessary.

I suppose that most of the used memory in Debug builds is the actual debugging information, zombie tracking etc.